# How to define the unique value in xml file

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I want to unique key in mobile number when two same mobile number found in xml file.

**My XML File :**

```
<EmployeeDetails>

    <Employee>
       <Name>ABC</Name>
       <MobileNumber>9876543210</MobileNumber>          
    </Employee>

    <Employee>
       <Name>XYZ</Name>
       <MobileNumber>9876543210</MobileNumber> 
    </Employee>

</EmployeeDetails>
```

**My XSD File :**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"> 
   <xs:element name="EmployeeDetails">
     <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Employee" maxOccurs="unbounded">
             <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                   <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                   <xs:element name="MobileNumber" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
             </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
```

When run the code if duplicate mobile number found then display error massage

Comment: Isn't it an error rather than something you want to "fix"? Or do you really want to allow employees with more than one name/ID or to support phones shared between employees? (I assume that `Name` is a unique user name rather than an actual name, otherwise you could have a problem if two employees have the same actual name...)

Comment: @Matthew Watson   I want to store unique mobile number not id or name.

Comment: So if you are using their mobile number as a unique key, it will be an error to have a duplicate one and therefore you should reject any attempt to add a duplicate to the database, rather than attempting to modify the number or adding an adjunct disambiguating key (IMO). But if you really want to do this, you could add a Guid for each record, and use THAT as the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Change your xsd with this code


<xs:element name="Name"/>
<xs:element name="MobileNumber" type="xs:long"/> 
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="Employee"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:unique name="Any name you want to give">
  <xs:selector xpath="Employee"/>
  <xs:field xpath="MobileNumber"/>
</xs:unique>
```